# Indexing k-th dimension of tensor with another tensor in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, indexing, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensor `probs` which has shape `(None, None, 110)` representing `(batch_size, sequence_length, 110)` in an LSTM. 
I have another tensor `indices` which has shape `(None, None)`, which contains the indices of the elements to select from the third dimension of `probs`.

I want to use `indices` to index the tensor `probs`.

Numpy equivalent:

```
k, j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(probs.shape[1]), np.arange(probs.shape[0]))
indexed_probs = probs[j, k, indices]
```

Since `shape[0]` and `shape[1]` of `probs` is not known, `tf.meshgrid()` is not an option. 
I found `tf.gather`, `tf.gather_nd` and `tf.batch_gather`, but they all don't seem to do what I want.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) like this:

```py
indexed_probs = tf.gather_nd(probs, tf.expand_dims(indices, axis=-1), batch_dims=2)
```

By the way, in NumPy you can use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) to do the same:

```py
indexed_probs = np.take_along_axis(probs, np.expand_dims(indices, axis=-1), axis=-1)[..., 0]
```

Comment: Do you by any chance also know how to do this in Keras? Apparently tf.keras.backend.gather_nd() does not exist yet...

Comment: Okay, I found out. :) You can add any tensorflow op as a Lambda layer in a keras model, like this: 
indexed_probs = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda probs_and_indices: tf.gather_nd(probs_and_indices[0], probs_and_indices[1], batch_dims=2), name='gather')([probs, indices])